# Function of %5c.. in a path traversal

Tags: vulnerability, encoding, directory-traversal, bug-bounty

I've recently come across this [blog post](https://shahmeeramir.com/traversing-the-path-to-5000-in-help-33750808704d) of a bug bounty hunter.

Apparently, a path traversal vulnerability was discovered, which looked like this:

```
 http://help.example.com/@app/skin/views/%5c../%5c../%5c../%5c../%5c../%5c../%5c../etc/passwd.html
```

I've never come across such a format for a path traversal.

How does this work and what is the purpose of the URL encoded backslash in `%5c..`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"%5c" (encoded backslash) is commonly used to circumvent sanitisation of the "../" (forward slash) in a URL - tries to stop directory transversal via the URL. As you can't have a backslash in a URL it needs to be encoded.

So if the forwardslash is blocked the backslash may work - allowing the attack.

I've seen this more often on IIS attacks rather than Linux/Unix servers.

Comment: So this is basically a circumvention of `../` filtering?

Comment: Yes. Another way of trying to move up a directory. If forward slash is stripped then make use of the backslash as most basic protection methods block ../

Comment: @BreakfastSerial Yes, I suspect an attempted bypass of `../` filtering. However, from its position, the (URI-encoded) backslash (`0x5c`) is more likely to be "protecting" the first of the dots (`.`) following it than the forward slash. Although it may work on some sites, the fact that `../` is still present "in plain text" suggests it won't be very effective against sites that have _some_ protection. A better attack might be `.../.%5c./.%5c./...` -- i.e. putting the backslash _between_ the two dots so `../` is no longer _directly_ visible.

Comment: can such attacks be prevented by mvc patterned web framework like laravel, spring